# How can I prevent subtraction from repeating?

Tags: vb.net, subtraction

I'm using vb.net
My condition is this:

Dim num1,num2  As Integer

num1 = TextBox1.Text

num2 = TextBox2.Text

TextBox3.Text = num1 - num2

The subtraction is working. My problem when I continuous clicking the button for result, its still subtracting. How can I prevent it if the value on the textbox is the same.. Or how can I make it subtracting once?

Example, MyStockTextBox minus ItemSoldTextBox. After I get the result by clicking the button, when I click the button again its still subtracting even if I'm done subtracting the two.

This is my code for subtraction.

```
Private Sub BtnResult_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Subtract.Click
    Dim num1, num2 As Integer
    num1 = TextBox1.Text
    num2 = TextBox2.Text
    TextBox3.Text = num1 - num2
End Sub
```

Comment: Please can you provide more details on your error. I am guessing that you mean txtbox3.text = txtbox1.text - txtbox2.text with some cost of number conversion happening. When are you calling this code (is it in an txtbox event) etc. Please past the code base in and we can help more

Comment: Conversion aside, you're writing this the wrong way. Try `txtbox3.text = txtbox1.text - txtbox2.text` .

Comment: Help me sir to solve this problem

Comment: You should show more code, so we can get an idea of what's going on. You're obviously beginning, and sometimes beginners do very surprising stuff.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error you describe.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code for subtraction.

Private Sub BtnResult_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Subtract.Click

```
    Dim num1,num2  As Integer 
    num1 = TextBox1.Text 
    num2 = TextBox2.Text 
    TextBox3.Text = num1 - num2
```

End Sub

Comment: Please delete this Answer. It is not an answer. I have added this to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, add this to the top of your code:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
```

Then you'll see a bunch of errors appear. That's a good thing. Currently, you're not managing your variable types, and at some point it's bound to be a problem, whether because you don't learn to manage them or just because the program is crashing because of it.

`Textbox1.Text` is a String type. You want to calculate numbers. You're bound to have a problem at some point.

Since you probably want Integers, here's a way you could safeguard this code snippet:

```
Dim num1, num2 As Integer

'If one of the textboxes contains something else than a number, your program won't crash. It returns 'True' when it's able to parse the String into an Integer and 'False' if it can't.
If Integer.TryParse(Number1TextBox.Text, num1) AndAlso Integer.TryParse(Number1TextBox.Text, num2) Then
    Number1TextBox.Text = (num1 - num2).ToString
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Use only integer numbers!")
End If
```

This doesn't prevent your code from running the operation more than once, but the result should be the same, so there will be no visible change on the screen.

There are several ways to prevent your user from repeating the same operation more than once, although I doubt that it would change much since the result won't change. Let me know if there's something I don't get.